# Do public/private/protected change the arrangement of a struct in memory?

Tags: c++, struct, mismatch

**Edit:** I just realized a much simpler way to ask this question:

> Given the following two structs:
>
> ```
> class Thing {public: int a; public: int b; public: int c;}
>
> class Thing {public: int a, private: int b; public: int c;}
> ```
>
> Are the members `a`, `b`, and `c` guaranteed to be in the same order in memory for both of these definitions?

---

### Old Question

Let's say we have this C++ code in `fileA.cpp`:

```
class Thing
{
public:
    int a;
    double num;

    Thing()
    {
        b = 10;
    }

    float getB()
    {
        return b;
    }

private:
    float b;
    Thing * other;
}

void doSomething(Thing thing);

int main()
{
    Thing thing;
    doSomething(thing);
    std::cout << thing.b;
}
```

And let's say we have this code in `fileB.cpp`:

```
class Thing
{
public:
    int a;
    double num;

    Thing()
    {
        b = 10;
    }

    float getB()
    {
        return b;
    }

    float b;

private:
    Thing * other;
}

void doSomething(Thing thing)
{
    thing.b = 30;
}
```

Assuming the compiler wouldn't complain, would this code work as expected? That being, is the arrangement of a struct's data independent of whether or not certain components are public, private, or protected?

**Edit:** To make it more obvious, the only difference between the two definitions of `Thing` is the fact that `float b;` is private in `fileA.cpp` but public in `fileB.cpp`.

Comment: Regardless of how they are laid out you violate the one definition rule.  You can only have one definition of an object.

Comment: This is what `friend` is for, or even better, proper object-oriented design to avoid this issue.

Comment: Yes, it will generate the same code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard makes no such guarantee. You have layout guarantees only for standard-layout classes:

> A standard-layout class is a class that:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> - has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
> - has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members,
> - has no non-standard-layout base classes,
> - either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with
>     non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
> - has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.

(C++14, [class] ¶7)

If a class is standard-layout, its layout is well defined (and two standard layout classes that have a layout-compatible initial sequence may read each other's layout-compatible members through a `union`).

However, here it is not the case, as you have different access specifiers throughout the class. In particular, it's explicitly stated that

> The order of allocation of non-static data members with different access control is unspecified

(C++14, [class.mem] ¶13)

---

*That being said*, I never worked with any real world compiler that ever exploited this flexibility offered by the standard - every compiler I know uses the access specifiers for compile-time checks, but ignores them completely as far as members layout is concerned.

Comment: I don't understand the rationale for this. What could possibly be achieved through this flexibility?

Comment: @Martin: it's a mystery to me as well; my only idea about that was that maybe some early implementation stored the members with different access control in separate lists, and then outputted them in a fixed order (e.g. first all public, then all protected, then all private), or that they were even outputted in the "underlying" C structure in separate sub-structures for some reason, but all these hypotheses seem far fetched.

Comment: Another possibility that comes to mind is that possibly they thought that, given that with access specifiers the class ceases to be C-style and thus subject to older APIs, compilers could exploit that opportunity to reorder members and reduce padding, but even this doesn't seem plausible.

Comment: Here there may be an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41407540/214671, something akin to my first thought (some existing implementation changed layout depending on the access specifiers).